# Библиотека для работы с изображениями | C++

Tags: c++, изображения

Решил сделать простенькую программу, которая текст с консоли конвертирует в набор единиц и нулей, а их шифрует в изображение черных и белых пикселей. Какую библиотеку использовать, чтобы была возможность создавать изображения попиксельно и чтобы можно было получить двумерный или многомерный массив с пикселями и RGBA информацией о изображении?
Знаю про OpenCV, но мне кажется, что это слишком тяжелая библиотека для подобной цели

Comment: Под виндой можно было бы заюзать GDI+. А у Вас какая операционка целевая?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://habr.com/ru/post/248153/

Можете использовать [формат TGA](https://github.com/ssloy/tinyrenderer/tree/909fe20934ba5334144d2c748805690a1fa4c89f). Там кроме массива пикселей и тривиального заголовка ничего не нужно.